# Select XML value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following XML format:

```
<ROOT>
   <ROW a="new" b="0.9209000" />
   <ROW a="old" b="0.0" />
</ROOT>
```

expected output:

```
SELECT new, new value, old ,old value
```

Comment: Your expected output never made it into the question.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Flatten two rows into one? What if there are *three* rows instead of just 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear. Here are all significant values from xml supplied:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<ROOT>
   <ROW a="new" b="0.9209000" />
   <ROW a="old" b="0.0" />
</ROOT>'

SELECT
    @xml.value('(ROOT/ROW[1]/@a)[1]','nvarchar(10)') New,
    @xml.value('(ROOT/ROW[1]/@b)[1]','decimal(9,7)') [New value],
    @xml.value('(ROOT/ROW[2]/@a)[1]','nvarchar(10)') Old,
    @xml.value('(ROOT/ROW[2]/@b)[1]','decimal(9,7)') [Old value]
```

**Result**

```
New    New value    Old    Old value
------ ------------ ------ ---------
new    0.9209000    old    0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nodes` to break down your xml to single rows, then you can build your expected output (which is not very clear):

```
declare @x xml
='<ROOT>
   <ROW a="new" b="0.9209000" />
   <ROW a="old" b="0.0" />
</ROOT>'

select 
     Tbl.Col.value('./@a', 'varchar(max)') as a
    ,Tbl.Col.value('./@b', 'varchar(max)') as b
from @x.nodes('/ROOT/ROW') Tbl(Col)
```

Results:

[image]